# Centering text in a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, texmaker

I have a table which needs to expand to the width of my page and I do this by

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centerline{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{Probability} \\ \hline
0 & 100 \% \\ \hline
998.13 & 60 \% \\ \hline
1996.26 & 31.37 \% \\ \hline
2994.39 & 16.11 \% \\ \hline
3992.52 & 8.26 \% \\ \hline
4990.64 & 4.23 \% \\ \hline
5988.77 & 2.17\% \\ \hline
6986.90 & 1.11\% \\ \hline
7828.46 & 0.63\% \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\caption{} 
\end{table}
```

however, the text is not becoming centered in the table , it is left justified. How can I center the text and get the text to be centered? (As I only managed one at a time)

Comment: Put in preambel ``\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}`` and then instead of ``X`` for column type use ``C``.

Comment: can you give me the whole line where I need to put it? since I am getting errors

Answer (score 5):

### Nice version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table example}
\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=4.2]
  S[table-format=3.2]
}
\toprule
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{Probability} (\si{\percent}) \\
\midrule
   0    & 100    \\
 998.13 &  60    \\
1996.26 &  31.37 \\
2994.39 &  16.11 \\
3992.52 &   8.26 \\
4990.64 &   4.23 \\
5988.77 &   2.17 \\
6986.90 &   1.11 \\
7828.46 &   0.63 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Two table variant

**Remarks:**

- The optional parameter of `tabular` or `tabularx` specifies, where the anchor of the table lies. `t` means the top element of the table (top rule or first row), `b` means the bottom line or last row. As default the table is vertically centered.
- Horizontal placement. First use `\centering` instead of `\centerline{...}`. `\centering` centers the lines of the paragraph, whereas `\centerline` restricts the contents to a `\hbox` and does not warn, if the elements do not fit in the current line width.
  If the two tables fit in one line, then `\hfill` inbetween will move the left table to the left and right table to the right side of the text area.
  The weaker `\hfil` can be used, if the free space between the tables should be equally distributed to the left of the left table, the middle between the tables and to the right of the right table.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Example with two tables}
\begin{tabular}[t]{
  S[table-format=4.2]
  S[table-format=3.2]
}
\toprule
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{Probability} (\si{\percent}) \\
\midrule
   0    & 100    \\
 998.13 &  60    \\
1996.26 &  31.37 \\
2994.39 &  16.11 \\
3992.52 &   8.26 \\
4990.64 &   4.23 \\
5988.77 &   2.17 \\
6986.90 &   1.11 \\
7828.46 &   0.63 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{
  S[table-format=4.2]
  S[table-format=3.2]
}
\toprule
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{Probability} (\si{\percent}) \\
\midrule
   0    & 100    \\
 998.13 &  60    \\
1996.26 &  31.37 \\
2994.39 &  16.11 \\
4990.64 &   4.23 \\
5988.77 &   2.17 \\
7828.46 &   0.63 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with two tables]

### Stretched to text width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table example}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{
  l
  @{\extracolsep\fill}
  S[table-format=4.2]
  S[table-format=3.2]
  l
}
\toprule
& \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Probability} (\si{\percent}) \\
\midrule
&    0    & 100    \\
&  998.13 &  60    \\
& 1996.26 &  31.37 \\
& 2994.39 &  16.11 \\
& 3992.52 &   8.26 \\
& 4990.64 &   4.23 \\
& 5988.77 &   2.17 \\
& 6986.90 &   1.11 \\
& 7828.46 &   0.63 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result enlarged]

### With ugly lines

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table example}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
  |S[table-format=4.2]|S[table-format=3.2]|
}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|X|}{\centering\textbf{Number}}
& \multicolumn{1}{X|}{\centering\textbf{Probability} (\si{\percent})} \\
\hline
   0    & 100    \\ \hline
 998.13 &  60    \\ \hline
1996.26 &  31.37 \\ \hline
2994.39 &  16.11 \\ \hline
3992.52 &   8.26 \\ \hline
4990.64 &   4.23 \\ \hline
5988.77 &   2.17 \\ \hline
6986.90 &   1.11 \\ \hline
7828.46 &   0.63 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with ugly lines]

### Centering without alignment of numbers

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table example}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
  |>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|
   >{\centering\arraybackslash}X<{\unskip~\%}|
}
\hline
\textbf{Number}
& \multicolumn{1}{X|}{\centering\textbf{Probability}} \\ \hline
   0    & 100    \\ \hline
 998.13 &  60    \\ \hline
1996.26 &  31.37 \\ \hline
2994.39 &  16.11 \\ \hline
3992.52 &   8.26 \\ \hline
4990.64 &   4.23 \\ \hline
5988.77 &   2.17 \\ \hline
6986.90 &   1.11 \\ \hline
7828.46 &   0.63 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result centered without number alignment]

Comment: Is there a way how I can insert 2 tables next to each other instead of enlarge it to text width please? (i.e. have 2 of the first example next to each other) That would be perfect!

Comment: how can I remove the alignment of number from the first table(the midrule etc one)?

Comment: @user1930901 Just use `cc` instead of `S[...]S[...]` as specification for the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is complete example which should clarify may comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
% definition of new column type should be in preamble of your document
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}%[H] if possible, avoid to use ``[H] 
             % option for placing of table, better is [htbp]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|C|}
\hline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{Probability} \\ \hline
0 & 100 \% \\ \hline
998.13 & 60 \% \\ \hline
1996.26 & 31.37 \% \\ \hline
2994.39 & 16.11 \% \\ \hline
3992.52 & 8.26 \% \\ \hline
4990.64 & 4.23 \% \\ \hline
5988.77 & 2.17\% \\ \hline
6986.90 & 1.11\% \\ \hline
7828.46 & 0.63\% \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{An important table ...}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

and lookout of table:

[image]

To my taste, the lookout of table in Heiko Oberdiek answer is (far) better.

Comment: please help me with this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246594/aligning-text-and-centering-in-a-table since I still cannot get it how I want to

Comment: But this question is removed from SE. For any help I need MWE in form as I give you in my answer (and Heiko Oberdiek). This is standard way to ask for help on SE.